# prove that $U=\cup ^{\infty}_{n=1}U_i$ where $U_i=\{x\in U| dist(x,\partial u)>1/i\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

prove that $U=\cup ^{\infty}_{n=1}U_i$ where $U_i=\{x\in U| dist(x,\partial u)>1/i\},
 i=1,2..$ and $U$ is bounded

suppose let 
$x\in \cup ^{\infty}_{n=1}U_i $ then $x\in U_i$ for some i so $x\in U$

conversely suppose if $x\in U$ then by archmedian  property  $xn>1$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

from here how to processed

Answer (score 0):

$U$ should be open as well along with being bounded. For the reverse inclusion pick a point $x \in U$, then use the fact that $\exists$ a nbd $N_x$ containing $x$ such that $N_x \subset U$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. In fact $\cup_i U_i$ is precisely $\{x: d(x ,\partial U) >0\}$ which is exactly the complement of the boundary of $U$ (which is the union of  interior of $U$ and the exterior of $U$).

For example if $U=[0,1]$ then $\cup_i U_i=\mathbb R \setminus \{0,1\}$ and if $U=(0,1)$ then also $\cup_i U_i$ is $\mathbb R \setminus \{0,1\}$